# Optional string variable in Terraform module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've a custom module to create task definitions on AWS ECS, which has a variable like this:

```
variable "extra_vars" {
  type = "string"
}
```

And inside my `main.tf` I do something like:

```
module "foo" {
  source = "git..."
  extra_vars =<<EOF
  {
   "name": "foo",
   "value": "bar"
  }
  EOF
}
```

The thing is this `extra_vars` variable is optional, but I needed it to be in JSON-like format as it's part of the ECS Task Definition, so I tried the following:

```
variable "extra_vars" {
  type = "string"
  default = "{}"
}
```

But it's failing.

My question here: is there any way to define optional string variables? Otherwise, can I set `extra_vars` to null or something?

Thanks.

= Update: This is where I need to use the variable:

```
"environment": [
{
    "name": "var0",
    "value": "value0"
},{
    "name": "var1",
    "value": "value1"
}, ${var.extra_vars}
]
```

Comment: How is it failing? `default = ""` would be an empty string..

Comment: please edit your question and add your code here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Have a look at the [template provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/index.html).